# R problems installing/loading tidyverse

Tags: r, installation, tidyverse

I am trying to load tidyverse but getting the following error message:

```
> library("tidyverse", lib.loc="C:/Program Files/R/R-3.5.1/library")
-- Attaching packages --------------------------------------- tidyverse 1.2.1 --
v ggplot2 3.1.0     v purrr   0.2.5
v tibble  1.4.2     v dplyr   0.7.6
v tidyr   0.8.1     v stringr 1.3.1
v readr   1.1.1     v forcats 0.3.0
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘tidyverse’:
 .onAttach failed in attachNamespace() for 'tidyverse', details:
  call: value[[3L]](cond)
  error: Package ‘tibble’ version 1.4.2 cannot be unloaded:
 Error in unloadNamespace(package) : namespace ‘tibble’ is imported by ‘broom’, ‘ggplot2’, ‘tidyr’, ‘modelr’, ‘readr’, ‘dplyr’, ‘haven’ so cannot be unloaded
In addition: Warning messages:
1: package ‘ggplot2’ was built under R version 3.5.2 
2: package ‘tibble’ was built under R version 3.5.3
```

When I simply try and load the package I get the error message:

```
> library(tidyverse)
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘tidyverse’ in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]):
 namespace ‘rlang’ 0.2.1 is being loaded, but >= 0.4.0 is required
```

I have searched all over google for answers.

I have tried installing tidyverse with dependencies.
I have also tried removing and installing the rlang package.

NB I am using R Studio Version 1.1.453

Comment: You have told us what version of Rstudio is being used but what is needed is the version of R. (Rstudio is **NOT** R.)The second error message and the warnings from the first makes me think you may have R version 4.?.? but am still using a package library for R version 3.5

Comment: @IRTFM apologies, I am using R version 3.5.1

Comment: Is there a reason you are using such an old version of R? It’s going to be difficult to make all these newer packages work in such an old version.

Comment: @MrFlick it was working alright before - but I ran install.packages(tidyverse) and the error came up. Was using tidyverse fine before that so can't work it out and don't know how to fix